# How to reference the last created page in SharePoint Pages Library within HTML

Tags: html, sharepoint

I am currently building custom html for a Sharepoint Site Page that i am building in SharePoint Online. One of the requirements of the page, is to include the latest page from a SharePoint Pages library and have it render within my HTML code.

In the past, i have used a content query web part to accomplish this to pull 1 page from the last created date, but since we are moving into a more customized look to our site, i wanted to see if this was possible.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In page load query the Pages library, order by Created Desc and Row Limit 1. Get the Data from the result page and bind it in your HTML markup.

Comment: Hi Naveen, I was able to query the Pages Library and came up with

function getPages()
$.ajax{{
url: https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/.....
type: "GET",
processData: False,
contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
headers: {
"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
},
window.onload=getPages;
}

Comment: Hi dmmedeiros, So that you can get the content of the Page, and bind that in your custom HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your response. how would i go about calling that query in my html? 

My thought would be 

<div id = "three" onload="getPages()">
</div>

Would be this the correct call for the function?

Comment: Ya. It would be good. Or else you can call it in document ready. $(document).ready(function(){getPages()});